# Quick way to add point features on a map

Tags: qgis, digitizing

I am looking for a quicker way to add points. I am mapping the buildings on a satellite imagery, but every time I add a point, I need to press enter to close the action menu.

Is there a way to add points without going through the action menu?

[image]

Comment: Assuming you have two hands... what is the hassle with pressing enter?

Comment: Also: `Options --> digitizing` - the topmost checkbox should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Handswise fortunately your assumption is right, but if you had to pinpoint >10'000 features, you would agree that an alternative would be welcomed.

It is indeed what I needed! thanks a lot @erik